# Is it possible for a Lorentz scalar to NOT be invariant under another linear transformation?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, inertial-frames, group-theory, linear-algebra

Lorentz scalars are invariant under Lorentz transformations, which are a subset of linear transformations. I wanted to know if it is possible, for a Lorentz scalar, to NOT be invariant with respect to another kind of linear transformation (e.g. scaling or whatever linear map other than Lorentz).

Can you mathematically prove your answer?

Comment: How about $3\times 7=21$ ?

Comment: Hint: in $2$ dimensions, which linear transformations preserve $t^2-x^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zero map $\mathbf u\mapsto \mathbf 0$ is linear, so yes - a generic linear transformation changes a Lorentz scalar. The *definition* of a Lorentz scalar is a quantity which is left invariant under Lorentz transformations - there's no reason whatsoever that this should extend to more general transformations.

Answer (score -1):

The Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$ has the property that its determinant
$$ \rm{det}(\Lambda)= \pm 1 $$

I can change $\Lambda$ such that it still remains a linear transformation but does not preserve the spacetime interval by having
$$ |\rm{det}(\Lambda)| \neq 1 $$

In this case, we have a linear transformation that fails to be Lorentz transformation. It also does not preserve the spacetime interval, which should be an invariant quantity.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. The accepted answers to me seems a special case of my answer i.e. when det($\Lambda$)=0.